# New to C and can't figure out these outputs

Tags: arrays, c

Hi I am new to c and trying to build just a simple print array however I just get what it wants to give me. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(){

    int n[5]={5,10,15,20,25};
    int i;

    printf("displaying integers:");
    for ( i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", &n[i]);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
displaying integers:6422280
6422284
6422288
6422292
6422296
```

Any help would be great I tried creating it as an enter integers and get an output but regardless of input it gave me extremely large numbers. which is why I'll be happy if it just prints. Sorry if it's an obvious one but I've tried 5 different ways all with similar/basically identical results.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`.

Comment: You print reference of array item. Remove ‚&’ before n to print value

Comment: Why print &n instead of just n?

Comment: You need `&` when you're calling `scanf`, **not** when you're calling `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

What you get printed are address locations of items stored in array.

If you want to print values of items in array, you should not use the address-of operator [ & ]. Try it this way:

printf("%d \n", n[i]);

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate the lesson along with it!